# log4j null pointer exception

Tags: java, log4j, nullpointerexception

Please ignore my ignorance with log4j and java. I am new and will appreciate all advice and any resource you can point me to. I inherited some code and I'm not sure where to start.

```
public class PagerManager {

private static Logger log = LogUtility.getLogger(PagerManager.class);
```

---

```
private void sendPage(String err_msg,String mail_to)
{
  //The log utility is giving me an error

  log.debug("Starting to send Mail Pager...");
```

---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at PagerManager.sendPage(PagerManager.java:71)
at PagerManager.sendMailPager(PagerManager.java:63)
at utilities.TestEmailAddress.TestEmailAddresses.sendPage(TestEmailAddresses.java:60)
at utilities.TestEmailAddress.TestEmailAddresses.main(TestEmailAddresses.java:33)
```

I get the error above when log4j tries to debug. If I remove all of the loggers from the code, the program works. I think it is not picking up the log4j.properties file that I also inherited.

Let me know if I can provide more information.

Thanks,
Eric

**UPDATE**

It appears the LogUtility is returning a null. I'm looking in to that currently.

**UPDATE**

LogUtility is where my problem lies. I will converse with my team about it later. Thanks for the help guys/gals. - Eric

Comment: What is `LogUtility`? I don't recognize that as part of log4j.

Comment: If the `log.debug("Starting ...` line is line number 71 than the log static member must be null, which means `LogUtility` (which is not part of log4J as mentioned by Jon Skeet) is returning null when called to initialize your static data member log.

Comment: I'll poke around and find out what LogUtility is. Thank, Eric

Answer (score 0):

1) The most likely cause is that your "log" object is null.  In general, thats what an NPE is.

2) There is another possibility : Of course, this is assuming that the log object is a normal Log4J class.  If it somehow is overriding the methods of the logger , which is entirely possible, then it could be looking for a logger resource inside of the override.